# unable to steam rtsp from mp4(h264) file using ffmpeg on os x: Connection refused Could not write header for output file

Tags: ffmpeg, tcp, h.264, rtsp

im ussing the following command on my macbook os high sierra to stream rtsp from mp4 file using ffmpeg:

```
sudo ffmpeg -re -i ./Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ar 44100 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8888/live
```

but get the following error:

```
[tcp @ 0x7fb979e22ec0] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:1935?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Connection refused
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

here is the whole output of the command:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
    artist          : Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
    composer        : Sacha Goedegebure
    encoder         : Lavf57.63.100
    comment         : Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net
    genre           : Animation
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 815 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 812 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fb97a00de00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb97a00de00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb97a00de00] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fb97a00de00] 264 - core 160 r3011 cde9a93 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=12 sliced_threads=1 slices=12 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[tcp @ 0x7fb979e22ec0] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:1935?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Connection refused
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

tried with and without sudo, tried changing rtsp://... to http://
also tried udp but get same output..

chacked that the port is not in use(8888) and different ports (1935...) but still the same.

i installed ffmpeg via brew install...

when i run some test server on my localhost i never have issues ussing an unused port

really stuck here and any help would be amazing...thank you

EDIT:
Problem was in the command i used: "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8888/live" - but i did not have a running server capable of accepting the data from ffmpeg and redestributing it - so i had to first run such server and only after that to run ffmpeg:

Servers which can receive from FFmpeg (to restream to multiple clients) include ffserver (linux only, though with cygwin it might work on windows), or ​Wowza Media Server, or ​Flash Media Server, Red5, or ​various others. Even ​VLC can pick up the stream from ffmpeg, then redistribute it, acting as a server.

i used the VLC option. You can read about it here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Comment: I've run into the same issue with macOS Ventura today. @TaIG did you solve it yourself? If i find a solution elsewhere i'll post again.

Comment: @Andreas this was a while back but from my recolection the ffmpeg aproach did not work for me. So i ended up using a grafic tool where i inputed all the params and used it instead of this command line tool "ffmpeg". I will try to search for more info from back when it happened. If ill find - ill put here in comment

Comment: @Andreas from what i remember: in the command i used: "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8888/live" - but i did not have a running server capable of accepting the data from ffmpeg and redestributing it - so i had to first run such server and only after that to run ffmpeg: Servers which can receive from FFmpeg (to restream to multiple clients) include ffserver (linux only, though with cygwin it might work on windows), or ​Wowza Media Server, or ​Flash Media Server, Red5, or ​various others. Even ​VLC can pick up the stream from ffmpeg, then redistribute it, acting as a server. - i used the VLC option

Comment: @TaIG i very much appreciate your input. Thank you.  

Just to add one solution not mentioned here. I found out OBS with the plugin obs-rtspserver working for me. Since you can script OBS you can control whatever is displayed in stream.